# How to change image logo on scroll with flip animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am trying to get animation to my navigation something like what is present in http://www.leodislager.com/.

In my present code I have managed to create the fixed navigation effect, but can't figure out how to get the flip logo animation on scroll -

Could anyone help me with the code for this?

Comment: You animate the width to 0, change the image source, and finally animate the width to the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples) is a nice place to look at rotation animations.
Another option (as Rory McCrossan suggested) is to write a script that alliteratively decreases the width of the picture to 0, changes the image and then increase the width to the wanted value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small crude(Very ugly looking) demo of what Rory was talking about. Actually it only demonstrates one part of the issue. But it is start and if you understand the logic then I'm pretty sure you will figure out the next part yourself. If you are stuck at any point SO is always there to help you

JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/a8cxrnxv/

JS

```
function OnScrollDiv(div) {
    var a = document.getElementById('header');
    var imgnew = a.childNodes[1].childNodes[0];
    imgnew.style.width = 100 - div.scrollTop + '%';
}
```